# Getting this to put on file and get rid of error code

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

This is supposed to put this information onto a new file but i get an error saying `'tuple' object has no object 'write'` so I need some help to figure out what is wrong in my code.

```
def codeData(filename):
    file = open(filename)
    outputFile = ("Project.txt", "w")
    #makes file that will take information from given file and write on it
    clinic = file.readline().strip()  #takes the name of clinic and writes it
    patientnumber = int(file.readline().strip())   #takes the amount of patients 

    for i in range(patientnumber):       
        outputFile.write("<patient>\n")
        outputFile.write("<patientID>"+file.readline().strip()+"</patientID>\n")
        outputFile.write("<clinic>"+clinic+"</clinic>\n")
        age = int(file.readline().strip())
        outputFile.write("<age>"+str(age)+"</age>\n")

        outputFile.write("<gender>"+gender+"</gender>\n")    
        height = int(file.readline().strip())

        outputFile.write("<height>"+str(height)+"</height>\n")
        weight = int(file.readline().strip())

        outputFile.write("<weight>"+str(weight)+"</weight>\n")
        hba1 = int(file.readline().strip())

        outputFile.write("<hba1>"+str(hba1)+"</hba1>\n")
        cholesterol = int(file.readline().strip())

        outputFile.write("<cholesterol>"+str(cholesterol)+"</cholesterol>\n")

        outputFile.write("<smoker>"+smoker+"</smoker>\n")

        systolic = int(file.readline().strip())
        outputFile.write("<systolic>"+str(systolic)+"</systolic>\n")

        diastolic = int(file.readline().strip())
        outputFile.write("<diastolic>"+str(diastolic)+"</diastolic>\n")

        file.close()
        outputFile.close()

    codeData("Project Text.txt")
```

Here is what is on the file that it takes in

```
UHIC
2
A31415
54
M
180
90
6.7
100
No
130
65
A32545
62
F
160
80
7.2
120
Yes
180
92
```

Comment: Okay update to this question is that i got it to run through once and it works through the first part of the list but i need it to go through again and i cant get it to do this so if anybody knows how to fix this please help?

Answer (score 0):

The error about the `tuple` not having a `write` method is happening because you didn't ever open your output file, you just put the arguments that would be passed to `open` in parentheses:

```
outputFile = ("Project.txt", "w") # need to call open here!
```

However, you should really use a `with` statement to open and close your two files:

```
with open(filename) as file, open("Project.txt", "w") as outputFile:
    # the rest of your code, skipping the close calls
```

You had a separate error, where the `close` calls were inside your loop. Using `with` makes manual closing entirely unneeded, so you don't need to worry about where to put the calls.

A further suggestion, unrelated to your current error: If you're reading or writing a structured file format (like XML), you should probably use a dedicated module for that input or output. It's much easier to learn an API than to make your own code to write it, and you'll be more likely to have it work right. For instance, it can be tricky when writing XML manually to be sure that you get all your tags closed correctly. (Your code doesn't appear to close its `<patient>` tags anywhere, so this may apply to you!)

I think for XML specifically, the `ElementTree` module (`xml.etree`) is probably the way to go if you want something in the standard library, but I've never actually used it so I can't speak authoritatively. There's also `xml.dom.minidom` plus scads of third party modules. Other people who have more hands on experience may be able to offer better advice about these options.